# How to set a figure title from a user input

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my code, the user can type in the name of a soccer player.

```
player1 = input('What is the first players name? ')
```

Is there a way to use the string inside the code that creates the chart's title so they don't have to do it manually every time?

#### add title

```
fig.text(0.515, 0.975, "Jacob Ramsey - Aston Villa", size=16,
         ha="center", color="#000000"
```

I've dug around and have not been successful as of yet.

Comment: `fig.text(0.515, 0.975, f"{player1} - Aston Villa", size=16, ha="center", color="#000000"` use f-strings, just like normal.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I enter the code as suggested

and I get the error message:
AssertionError: Number of highlights (0) should be equal to number of highlight_textprops (2)

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtvdv.png)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney  I was able to get it to work; you're my hero. Thank you.

Comment: What was wrong?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney After I entered the string into Player1, I ran more code, and it changed Player1. So, I used Players2 when I ran the additional code to Player1 and could still pull in Player1 to the title. I'm sure that is as clear as mud, but I hope you understand. :)